# Cast an unsigned short/int to char *

Tags: c++, qt, casting, char, qbytearray

I have a function like this

```
void UnitTestWorker::constructTestPayload(QByteArray &payload)
{
    QString List = "127.0.0.1";
    unsigned short Port = 12344;
    unsigned int RequestId = 1;
    memcpy(payload.data(),reinterpret_cast<char*>Port,sizeof(Port));
    memcpy(payload.data()+sizeof(Port),reinterpret_cast<char*>RequestId ,sizeof(RequestId ));
}
```

But I am getting access violation error, it seems like I can't do something like `reinterpret_cast<char*>Port` or `reinterpret_cast<char*>RequestId`.

Comment: Did you mean`&Port` for that reinterpret cast ? Similarly for `&RequestId` ? Casting the *value* of an `unsigned short` or `int` to `char*` would be rather wonky. I suspect you mean to use their addresses.

Comment: even changing to &Port and & RequestID i am getting the correct things is it because char   : 1 byte
short  : 2 bytes

Comment: I have no idea what you just said.

Answer (score 1):

You have to ensure that `QByteArray &payload` has a sufficient size to receive the data you byte copy to it:

```
if (payload.size()<sizeof(Port)+sizeof(RequestId)) 
    throw exception ("Ouch !! payload too small"); 
memcpy(payload.data(),reinterpret_cast<char*>(&Port),sizeof(Port));
memcpy(payload.data()+sizeof(Port),reinterpret_cast<char*>(&RequestId) ,sizeof(RequestId ));
```